# Подключение к бд, ловит исключение

Tags: java, mysql

Не получается почему-то подключиться к бд. Кэтч ловит исключение.

```
public class Main {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest?useSSL=false";
    private static final String LOGIN = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydbtest?useSSL=false", "root", "root");
            if(!connection.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("TRUE");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Невозможно подлючиться к БД!");
        }

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать e.printStackTrace() ?

Comment: версия java? версич драйвера jdbc?

Comment: DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver());

Comment: @Вадим это не помогает.

Comment: @QertuUerty Вот ошибка.

Comment: Две извечные проблемы, кодировки и часовые пояса.

Comment: Разобрался. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Не могли бы добавить главный кусок исключения ( первую строку ) в само сообщение, чтобы другие могли найти ваш вопрос и приложенный ответ ?

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в том, что база данных отправляет тайм-зону на Русском языке. В тоже время у вас вероятней всего еще и проблема с кодировкой.

Для того, чтобы "исправить" ошибку с тайм-зоной ( при этом использовать не правильное время, подойдет для локального девелопмента ) можно добавить serverTimezone=UTC как параметр JDBC. Так же возможным решением является изменить кодировку MySQL и JDBC на одну и туже.

Еще один из вариантов - изменить тайм-зону самого MySQL с помощу данного SQL запроса ( изменит время на UTC+3, Москва. Еще как вариант это "Europe/Moscow" ):

```
SET time_zone = "+3:00"
```

Comment: @Roman Исправил, спасибо.